# blogSchema is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating APIs for a blog application and the API through which I will get all blogs, showing some error. My app.js(which is the API file) and blogModel.js(which is the schema file) has been written below. Please help me in finding the error.

```js
///////////////////app.js/////////////////////////
//calling the module
var express = require('express');


//cretaing an instance
var app = express();


//calling body-parser and cookie-parser
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');


//calling mongoose module
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var newBlog = [];


//using body-parser and cookie-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit : '10mb', extended : 'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit : '10mb', extended : 'true'}));
app.use(cookieParser());

//Defining configuration of mongoDB or at BlogApp it will create Database
var dbPath = "mongodb://localhost/BlogApp";


//Telling mongoDB to connect at dbPath or connect database
db = mongoose.connect(dbPath);


//Checking connection is open or not
mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
 console.log("connection is established");
})


//Including the schema file or Blog Model file
var Blog = require('./blogModel.js');


//To play with the data which will be store in blog or perform various functions on db using 
//blogData variable
var blogData = mongoose.model('Blog');


//A simple route to check app is working or not correctly
app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.send("Application in on and it's working very fine. Stay in touch to get latest updates");
})

//Mian routes fro blog Application
//1.) Route to get all the blogs
app.get('/blogs',function(req, res) {
 blogData.find(function(err,result){
  if(err) {
   console.log(err);
  }
  else {
   console.log(result);
   res.send(result);
  }
 })
});



//2.) Route to create a Blog



app.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log("Listening on port 3000");
})



///////////blogModel.js///////////////////////
//Calling the module
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//using the schema part of the module
var blogSchema = mongoose.Schema;

//creating an instance
var blogData = new blogSchema({

 blogId         :  {type : String, default : ''},
 blogCreatedOn       :  {type : Date, default : null},
 blogHeading        :  {type : String, default : ''},
 blogSubHeading       :  {type : String, default : ''},
 blogBody        :  {type : String, default : ''},
 imageUrl        :  {type : String, default : 'https://www.google.com'},
 blogAuthorName       :  {type : String, default : ''}

});

//blogData is schema name
mongoose.model('Blog', blogData);
```

My error is:-
=>blogSchema is not defined.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should export your model to be able to require it. so in `blogModel.js` file change this:

```
mongoose.model('Blog', blogData);
```

to this one:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Blog', blogData);
```

And in your app.js use `Blog` to query it:

```
var Blog = require('./blogModel.js');

// var blogData = mongoose.model('Blog');

//1.) Route to get all the blogs
app.get('/blogs',function(req, res) {
    Blog.find(function(err,result){ ...
```

Comment: Hi @dNitro. I tried that but still it's showing same error.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dNitro. It worked out. Thank you so much